# using scroll and bulk api to reindex data from one index to another

Tags: elasticsearch

Aim is to move data/documents from source index to destination index.

using scroll api i could be able to retrieve batch of results from source index , and ES documentation says that bulk api should be used to update destination index, how can i use the results of scroll api in bulk api so that destination index is built.

Comment: Why not using the [reindex API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html) which does exactly that?

Comment: i am using 2.4.1 version ES , i guess reindex is not so well supported in that version , so i opted to consider scroll and bulk api to achieve this , let me know how i can do using scroll& Bulk Api

Comment: "not so well supported" what makes you think that? Have you tried it?

Comment: i tried using bulk api for a scenario where mapping of type in source index is different to destination index , in such case below error is thrown.
{
            "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
            "reason": "Can't specify parent if no parent field has been configured"
         }